# Can you find the pattern to this number sequence?

Tags: number-sequence

The sequence is

> $1, 4, 16, 27, 256, 3125, 46656, 65536, 823543, 16777216, 387420489, 10000000000, 285311670611, 7625597484987, 8916100448256$

Can you figure out the pattern to this sequence of numbers?

Comment: Just to be sure, 16 is really in this sequence?

Comment: Yes 16 really is in this sequence.

Comment: It's a very interesting sequence, and the math behind it is fascinating, but we are somewhat picky about number sequence *puzzles* on this site: a puzzle whose solution can be found in the [bible](http://oeis.org/A257309) is not going to fare all that well. There are a couple of other hints on creating good (and bad) number sequence puzzles in the [tag wiki](/tags/number-sequence/info) and the linked [meta question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/number-sequence-puzzles-what-not-to-do). So please do keep posting, and welcome to PSE!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick search on OEIS give:

> [The Hyper-4 powers](http://oeis.org/A257309) also known as [Tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)

Basically:

> This is a sorted list of  $a^a$, $b^{b^b}$, $c^{c^{c^c}}$ and so on... where $a,b,c,...$ are Natural numbers greater than 2 (1 is the offset in this case, 1^(any number) gives 1 )
>  So, the next term is: 13**13 =  302875106592253

Comment: It didn’t ask for the next term lol

Comment: @thecoder16 I "extrapolated" that bit :P

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Besides 16, the sequence is

> $n^n$. $1^1=1$, $2^2=4$, $3^3=27$, etc.